# iOS how to animate view moving offscreen for portrait and landscape when using autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I'm looking for a way to move a UIView offscreen with a swipe gesture. I got everything set up, but noticed that the code below moves the panel down, rather than offscreen in portrait mode. **Is there a way for me to specify "Move UIView to the right by x pixels, regardless of device orientation or autolayout?**  Maybe dynamically changing the "leading space to superview" is the answer?

```
   CGPoint sidePanelCenter = self.sidePanel.center;
   float width = self.sidePanel.bounds.size.width; 

   self.sidePanel.center = CGPointMake(sidePanelCenter.x-width, sidePanelCenter.y);
```

Comment: you can adjust to UIView size according to that from your XIB file. or if you are using auto layout just make your UIView Centre  Vertically and than iOS will handle the constrain them selves.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `NSLayoutConstraint` that sets the `UIView` position as an IBOutlet and change it in code instead of the `center` property.